# Can anyone suggest compatibility versions of hadoop, sqoop, hbase and hive

Tags: hive, hbase, sqoop, hadoop2

I used hadoop 2.5.2, hbase 0.98.* version,hive 1.2.1 versions. Now sqoop is not compatible with hadoop version. If i change hadoop>2.5 hbase and hive will not support. Can anyone helps me to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the compatible versions of the Hadoop ecosystem installed on Cloudera Virtual Machine cdh5.3.10.

Your mentioned Hadoop version 2.5.2 should be compatible with the list as well.

- hadoop-2.5.0
- hbase-0.98.6
- hive-0.13.1
- hue-3.7.0
- oozie-4.0.0
- pig-0.12.0
- sqoop-1.4.5
- sqoop2-1.99.4
- zookeeper-3.4.5

I am not sure the reason behind installing Hadoop and its components on your system, but if you just want to learn Hadoop framework then i recommend to start with installing Cloudera QuickStart virtual machine on your OSX system provided your system has all the hardware prerequisites:

http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-8.html

Cloudera QuickStart virtual machines include everything you need to try Hadoop, MapReduce, Hive, Pig, Impala, etc. and Eclipse IDE as well.

See my answer here: [Hadoop : how to start my first project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002420/hadoop-how-to-start-my-first-project/42009985#42009985)

Comment: No actually I am not a learner I am a developer. Before I had configured with the technologies but right now when i am running same versions i am facing configuration issues.

Comment: Well then above list should work for you as these versions are compatible and are installed in CDH 5.3

Comment: Be aware that the versions of the tools bundled in CDH are **quite inconsistent** with the Apache versions. For instance, CDH 5.9 is supposed to ship with Hadoop 2.6.0 but there so many back-ports from V2.6.5 and/or 2.7.x and/or 2.8.beta that the "2.6.0" is just a joke.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer Apache release versions from HDP. You can use:

- Apache Hadoop 2.7.1
- Apache HBase 1.1.2
- Apache Hive 1.2.1
- Apache Sqoop 1.4.6

(*Refereed from [HDP 2.4.2](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.2/bk_HDP_RelNotes/content/ch_relnotes_v242.html)*)

Comment: i installed hadoop 2.7.1 version n sqoop 1.4.6 n java 1.7. When i am importing data from mysql to hdfs through sqoop i am getting an error ERROR [main] tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: No enum constant org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobCounter.MB_MILLIS_MAPS...
CAN U TELL ME WHERE IS THE PROBLEM